# How to resolve 'R' status

Tags: svn

I understand that `R` means that someone checked in a change to the repo before I did.

```
PS C:\SVN\files> svn st
R  +    file1.txt
R  +    file2.txt
```

How do I get rid of `R  +` when using `svn st`?

```
PS C:\SVN\files> svn --version
svn, version 1.12.2 (r1863366)
   compiled Aug  4 2019, 18:52:55 on x86-microsoft-windows
```

Comment: With `svn commit`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was:

```
PS C:\SVN\files> svn revert file1.txt

PS C:\SVN\files> svn revert file2.txt
```